# How do I check out a file in tfs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I have a Setup/Deployment project for my C# and attempting to delete a file from the 'File System on Target Machine' -> Application Folder -> ConverterModule. But I get this error:

> The command you are attempting cannot
>   be completed because the file
>   'AS_renderingServer.vdproj' is under
>   source code control and is not checked
>   out.

How do I check out a vdproj-file? According to Microsoft I should:

> In Solution Explorer, select the
>   referenced file. On the File menu,
>   choose Check Out.

That sounds pretty easy, except that the vdproj-file doesn't seem to appear anywhere in the Solution Explorer. How can I select it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Team Explorer, double click on "Source Control" inside your team project and locate the file in the source control browser.
Alternatively, simple right click on the setup project in the solution explorer and select "Check Out for edit...", because that project represents the project file.

Comment: Hi. There isn't a "Check Out for edit..." on my deployment project. But I could navigate to the file in Source Control Explorer and manually check it out.

Answer (score 1):

If the file you wish to check out isn't in your solution, you can also check out files by browsing to the file in question in Team Explorer \ Source Control .. right click the file to Check Out for Edit